# Android: Bluetooth(Chat) App should always be kept available in the background

Tags: android, service, sdk, background, bluetooth

i want to control my phone using an external bluetooth-device with SPP (RFCOMM).
so i took the BluetoothChat-Example and adopted the read-part to handle my commands sent by the external device.
when i use the external device, it powers up, establishes a connection, sends the command and turns off again. the app is also working when running in the background. so everything works fine so far ..

the two problem i still have are:

a) if i switch-off and on bluetooth on the phone, it will no longer listen to incoming connections from the external device. i have to start the app again to make it work.

b) closing the app is also ok, the thing still works. but when i kill all processes, the app is also closed and will not work longer. is there a possibility, to relaunch the app automatically?

thanks!

PS: i am an android beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Bluetooth yet but I think I can give you some pointers with my experience in Android

a) I assume you have implemented a Service for the Bluetooth connection, right? If so, you could implement a Broadcast receiver for ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED event. When receiving this broadcast, you could handle the Bluetooth device connection and disconnection.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED

b) I am not really sure if you can achieve this. If you program an Alarm with the system AlarmManager to reopen your app and the OS kills your process, the Alarms are also killed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: tnx andres,
a) i did not implement a service yet. i will have a look on the broadcast-receiver, this sounds interesting!
b) i have seen applications doing this. for example widgetlocker. it is automatically started after being killed.

Comment: Hi hewald. I think you can achieve this behaviour by implementing a service which runs in another process (android:process) and checks periodically if your core service is alive.

Comment: i agree with you. the first atempt to change the program to a service resulted in crashing the program, but this will be my next challenge to make it work ...

Comment: Hello, i know that this post is old, but only for information you can use ACTION_STATE_CHANGED for the BrodcasReceiver, and you can validate every state, for example BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON.

Answer (score 0):

i managed to run the service and it works fine!
i also added a broadcastreceiver for boot_complete-event - works also.

the only problem which is unsolved until now is, that when i kill all processes my service and receiver stop working!
is there a way to keep them alive or restart them automatically?
thanks!